# Xslt select text from middle of value but start from right

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a string in an element where I need to pull the U.S. State.  I can't use Substring because the start of the string is the city so the number of characters isn't static.  I can grab it from the right since that is the zip code.  How do I use a substring (or other function) to grab the state in the middle.  Here is an example.

PITTSBURGH PA 15213

Thank you.

Comment: Is the State always stored as a two-character value, preceded and followed by a space, after which you see a five character zip code?

Comment: Yes.  Always. That's why I'm hoping to grab it from the right.

Answer (score 2):

`substring(foo, string-length(foo) - 8, 2)` should do.

Answer (score -2):

you could use `substring-after` and `substring-before`, such as:

```
substring-before(substring-after(., ' '), ' ')
```